# Is there a way to prevent flickering when recompose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I want to make a infinite running step as the image below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTxBK.png)
I have a drawMap to handle the offset of the views, each period of time the offset will change and the views are redrawn

```
sealed class StepData(var offset: Dp) {
    class DotDiv(offset: Dp): StepData(offset)
    class Step(offset: Dp, val stepNumber: Int): StepData(offset)
}

/**
 *      walkStepWidth          dotDivWidth
 *          |                       |
 *   |---[100]---[101]---[102]---[103]---| <-- screen boundary
 *   |<--------->|
 *       offset
 */
@Preview
@Composable
fun WalkStepLine(startStep: Int = 100, endStep: Int = 200, transitionPerSecond: Dp = 100.dp) {
    var boxWidth by remember {
        mutableStateOf(0.dp)
    }
    var isUpdateUI by remember {
        mutableStateOf(0)
    }
    val walkStepWidth = 58.dp
    val walkStepHeight = 24.dp
    val dotSize = 6.dp
    val dotSpacing = 8.dp
    val dotNumberPerDiv = 3
    val dotDivWidth =
        (dotSize.value * dotNumberPerDiv + dotSpacing.value * (dotNumberPerDiv + 1)).dp
    var lastStepNumber = remember {
        0
    }
    val drawMap = remember {
        LinkedList<StepData>()
    }
    val fps = 64
    //per frame the layout will move to left a stepPace dp
    val stepPace = remember {
        transitionPerSecond/fps
    }
    var calculateStepPace = remember {
        stepPace
    }
    var shouldSkipFrame = remember {
        false
    }

    //init step view
    LaunchedEffect(key1 = boxWidth, block = {
        if (boxWidth>0.dp){
            drawMap.clear()
            drawMap.apply {
                var calculateOffset = boxWidth-dotDivWidth
                addFirst(StepData.DotDiv(offset = calculateOffset))
                calculateOffset -= walkStepWidth
                addFirst(StepData.Step(offset = calculateOffset, stepNumber = startStep+2))
                calculateOffset -= dotDivWidth
                addFirst(StepData.DotDiv(offset = calculateOffset))
                calculateOffset -= walkStepWidth
                addFirst(StepData.Step(offset = calculateOffset, stepNumber = startStep+1))
                calculateOffset -= dotDivWidth
                addFirst(StepData.DotDiv(offset = calculateOffset))
                calculateOffset -= walkStepWidth
                addFirst(StepData.Step(offset = calculateOffset, stepNumber = startStep))
                calculateOffset -= dotDivWidth
                addFirst(StepData.DotDiv(offset = calculateOffset))
                lastStepNumber = startStep+3
            }
        }
    })
    LaunchedEffect(key1 = true, block = {
        while (!(lastStepNumber > endStep && drawMap.last is StepData.DotDiv && drawMap.last.offset <= boxWidth - dotDivWidth)) {
            delay(1000L/fps)
            if (shouldSkipFrame){
                calculateStepPace +=stepPace
            }
            else {
                val iterator = drawMap.iterator()
                while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                    val stepData = iterator.next()
                    if (stepData is StepData.DotDiv) {
                        if (stepData.offset + dotDivWidth < 0.dp) {
                            iterator.remove()
                        } else {
                            stepData.offset -= calculateStepPace
                        }
                    } else if(stepData is StepData.Step) {
                        if (stepData.offset + walkStepWidth < 0.dp) {
                            iterator.remove()
                        } else {
                            stepData.offset -= calculateStepPace
                        }
                    }
                }
                val last = drawMap.last
                val rightNewStepOffset = boxWidth
                if (last is StepData.Step) {
                    val endOffsetOfTheLast = last.offset + walkStepWidth
                    if (endOffsetOfTheLast < rightNewStepOffset) {
                        drawMap.add(StepData.DotDiv(offset = endOffsetOfTheLast))
                    }
                } else if (last is StepData.DotDiv) {
                    val endOffsetOfTheLast = last.offset + dotDivWidth
                    if (endOffsetOfTheLast < rightNewStepOffset && lastStepNumber<=endStep) {
                        drawMap.add(
                            StepData.Step(
                                offset = endOffsetOfTheLast,
                                stepNumber = lastStepNumber++
                            )
                        )
                    }
                }
                isUpdateUI++
            }
        }
    })
    val density = LocalDensity.current
    BoxWithConstraints(modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .clipToBounds()
        .onGloballyPositioned {
            with(density) {
                val widthInDp = it.size.width.toDp()
                if (widthInDp > 0.dp && widthInDp != boxWidth) {
                    boxWidth = widthInDp
                }
            }
        }, contentAlignment = Alignment.CenterStart
    ) {
        if (isUpdateUI != -1) {
            drawMap.forEachIndexed { index, stepData ->
                if (index == 0) shouldSkipFrame = true
                if (stepData is StepData.Step) {
                    Box(modifier = Modifier.offset(stepData.offset, 0.dp)) {
                        WalkStep(
                            width = walkStepWidth,
                            height = walkStepHeight,
                            stepNumber = stepData.stepNumber
                        )
                    }
                } else if (stepData is StepData.DotDiv) {
                    Row(
                        modifier = Modifier.offset(
                            stepData.offset,
                            0.dp
                        )
                    ) {
                        for (i in 0 until dotNumberPerDiv) {
                            if (i == 0) {
                                HorizontalSpacer(width = dotSpacing)
                            }
                            WalkDot()
                            HorizontalSpacer(width = dotSpacing)
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (index == drawMap.size - 1) {
                    shouldSkipFrame = false
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Preview
@Composable
fun WalkStep(width: Dp = 58.dp, height: Dp = 24.dp, stepNumber: Int = 0, strokeColor: Color = Color(0xFF8CD5FF)) {
    Surface(
        shape = OvalCornerShape(width = 58.dp, height = 24.dp),
        border = BorderStroke(width = 2.dp, strokeColor),
        modifier = Modifier
            .width(58.dp)
            .height(24.dp)
    ) {
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(Color.White),
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
        ) {
            Text(text = "$stepNumber", color = TextPrimaryColor, style = MaterialTheme.typography.FuturaBold16)
        }
    }
}

@Preview
@Composable
fun WalkDot(size: Dp = 6.dp) {
    Surface(
        shape = androidx.compose.foundation.shape.CircleShape,
        modifier = Modifier
            .size(6.dp)
    ) {
    }
}

class OvalCornerShape(
    val width: Dp, val height: Dp
) : Shape {

    override fun createOutline(
        size: Size,
        layoutDirection: LayoutDirection,
        density: Density
    ): Outline {
        val widthPx = with(density){
            width.toPx()
        }
        val heightPx = with(density) {
            height.toPx()
        }
        val rect = Rect(
            offset = Offset(0f, 0f),
            size = Size(width = widthPx, height = heightPx)
        )
        val path = Path().apply {
            addOval(rect)
        }
        return Outline.Generic(path)
    }
}
```

It works well but sometimes the number flicker, I try to fix this but it's didn't work. I'm a newbie in compose, please help me. Sorry for my bad English.